# Фотография пользователя

Tags: php

Чтобы не допустить ошибку, подскажите, какой из вариантов лучше:

1. Загрузка аватара, если пользователю понадобиться сменить его, то старый удаляется, а новый записывается после загрузки (экономия памяти на сервере).
2. Сделать, как в популярных социальных сетях (с фотоальбомами).

Comment: Всё зависит от имеющегося места на диске.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это вопрос вкуса (и места на ЖД сервера).
Если предполагаешь, что пользователю будут нужны старые фотки, то делай альбомы, если нет - удаляй нафиг - места больше и мороки меньше (для альбомов код побольше будет).